# Discord.js - Set doesn't affect the bot

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently in the middle of writing a Quiz Bot and added a little set to make sure the quiz taker doesn't restart mid-quiz.

So I have basically added the set, and upon messaging the bot 'start', it will add the user to the set and won't remove him until 10 minutes later, which is the time span that you have to complete the quiz by.

While running the bot itself, the set doesn't really seem to affect the bot at all, and if you do happen to message him "start" mid-quiz he will restart it without any issues - I have also tested this by attempting at typing 'hello' in the console if the user attempts to do so, but nothing happens yet again.

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

```
client.on('message', async message => {
const midQuiz = new Set()
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
let mistakes = 0;
if (message.content === 'start') {
    if (message.channel.type == "dm") {
                if (midQuiz.has(message.author.id)) {
                    console.log('hello')
                    return message.author.send('You're currently mid-quiz! You may not restart it now.')
                } else {
                    midQuiz.add(message.author.id)
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        midQuiz.delete(message.author.id)
                        message.author.send('10 minutes have gone by and you have not completed the quiz, therefore you have failed.')
                    }, 600000)
                    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Verification Quiz")
                    .setDescription("Question #1: What is the owner's name?")
                    .setColor(3426654)
                    .setFooter("You may type 'cancel' at any time to stop the quiz.")
                    message.author.send(Embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `midQuiz` *inside* the `message` event, making it so that the set gets redeclared and reset every single message.

```js
// outside of the event
const midQuiz = new Set();

client.on('message', ...);
```